# Firefox Issue: when a script tag is injected within an iframe onload event fires too early?

Tags: javascript, firefox

This issue only occurs in Firefox. I am trying to inject a script tag inside an iframe and carry out some task when the script tag has completed loading using the onload handler.

```
document.open();
document.write(`<iframe id="temp"><html><head></head><body></body></html></iframe>`);
document.close();

var elem = document.getElementById('temp');
var doc = elem.contentDocument;
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.onload = function() {
    alert(elem.contentWindow.getVPAIDAd); 
}
scr.onerror = function() {
    alert('error');
}
scr.src = 'https://googleads.github.io/googleads-ima-html5/vpaid/linear/VpaidVideoAd.js';
console.log(doc.head.appendChild(scr));
```

The same code can be tested in JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv76L2yr/5/ . The JS Fiddle works perfectly in Google Chrome since onload gets trigggered after the script tag is loaded, however in firefox this does not seem to be happening. Any possible solutions to fix this in firefox??

Comment: If I use a script that isn't blocked by my Adblocker extension, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/t7wkdxqs/

Comment: Hi, the question does not try to imply that onload does not get called, the question tries to point out that when an implementation dependent on the availability of the external JS File is carried out it fails in firefox.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you expect Firefox to call `onload` even though the external file isn't available...? Why? To be clear: your code doesn't work in Chrome for me either, because uBlock Origin, which I have active in both browsers, blocks the script. If I deactivate it, the code displays the function just fine.

Comment: So, just to confirm are you saying that when you do deactivate uBlock Origin, the code displays the function just fine on both chrome and firefox? Because when I do try the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/sv76L2yr/5/ on firefox, the output i get is undefined and not the function which is expected.

Comment: It works like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/t7wkdxqs/

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle with similar changes, the idea is to not use document.write but inject the element into HTML using document.body.appendChild, I am not exactly sure why this is the case but this seems to work.. https://jsfiddle.net/sv76L2yr/25/